# How to save string using angularJS or Java (and use it in iframe)?

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, iframe

Here is what I intend to do:

Using a Java web service, I get the HTML content from a URL (Jsoup) and return it as a string to the caller, in the case an Angular or JS script. I want to save this content somewhere, and then put it into an Iframe or something similar.

My purpose is to change a bit the HTML before returning it.
So, how could I show an HTML string into an iframe? Or I needed to save it into an HTML file, and then show it in the iframe? Is there a better solution than an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not an ideal time to use an iframe, an iframe does not let you alter the html it gives you. use the directive ng include. so you can save your html and add your lines. then include it with `<ng-include src="(yourhtmlsource)"></ng-include>`

Comment: I think it will work better, I just have the problem with the hyperlinks inside the html, which point to local files I don't have... But it's a problem with my logic haha

Comment: I think I'll use a java web service to treat the HTML script (jsoup makes things easier) and then use it (iframe or include)